# Google Sheets images

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, images, google-chrome-extensions

When I insert an image in a cell in Google Sheets from my camera how is that image stored in the cell?  I know it creates an image in my phone in a folder called images, but if I want to link that picture to some function in Google Sheets how do I do that?

I am trying to figure out how to make a pop out picture or make the pictures larger on click somehow.  All the sources I have found require a URL or file location.  I don't know what the location of these pictures is.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The picture you inserted into Google Sheets' cell is hosted/located on Google's server (exact location/address is unknown). In other words - you "made a copy" of your picture from your device to Google Sheets.

Once the image is **in the cell** you are able to simply refer to that cell like:

[image: 0]

And further, you are able to use this reference in formulas like:

[image]

However, if you want to have a popup/hover of the original size on demand you will need to do it like this:

- upload your image on some image hosting site (Imgur for example)
- create a hyperlink with **`HYPERLINK`** function

  ```
  =HYPERLINK("https://i.stack.imgur.com/59xZ9.png", A38)
  ```
- and install this extension: **[Hover Zoom+](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hover-zoom%20/pccckmaobkjjboncdfnnofkonhgpceea)**
- then just point your cursor on the link

[image: 0]